# The best practice to avoid warning C26451 [Typecast error]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am working on coding exercises for C++ beginner on Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) with Visual Studio Community 2019. I would like to know the best practice for typecast. Below is what I tried. Could you please anyone give me some advice? Thank you in advance.

I initialized as below:

```
// "long int" 4 bytes
long m = 2;

// double  8 bytes
double x = 2 * m;
```

Then I got warning C26451:"Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2)."

So I corrected as below and warning disappeared.
Is there any other way to fix the problem other than below?

```
// "long int" 4 bytes
long m = 2;

// double  8 bytes
double mConvertToDouble;
mConvertToDouble = static_cast<double>(m);
double x = 2 * mConvertToDouble;
```

Comment: `2. * m;`, by putting the `.` on the `2`, it makes the `2` into a double, and thus the `m` will be automatically converted to a double prior to multiplication. (note that `m`, which defined as `long` is going to be an `int`, because that's how VS treats `long`)

Comment: Why would you do that conversion tho'?

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you so much for your advice. I tried the workaround you suggested and it worked! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @newbie99 Thank you for your question. This is because I got the typecast error C26451 as I stated above. Do I answer your question?

Comment: @newbie99 Also I wanted to practice how to typecast correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind is that `C26451` is not a "compiler warning". It's from the [C++ Core Guidelines checker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers) which is a modern [lint-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) tool.

IOW: It's extremely fussy by design. The code you wrote is in fact valid source code.

The [C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) are a great guide for C++ developers and a great resource, but a lot of it can be summed up as "recommended in many cases, but not required and maybe not appropriate in all cases".

The "issue" it's telling you is that in `double x = 2 * m;`, you may not realize it's actually doing the `*` operator as a 32-bit single-precision and then converting it to 64-bit double-precision. This is potentially a "portability bug" because on an architecture with 64-bit `long`, then it will have different results in edge-cases than in a system like Windows x86/x64 which has 32-bit `long`. This is also potentially a 'security bug' in the sense that you get different 'overflow/underflow' behavior.

You can 'fix' this any number of ways. If you really want a `double`, then as noted in the comments, you should make it clear that the `2` is intended as a `double` literal:

```
double x = 2.0 * m;
```

> You can also of course just disable the C++ Core Guidelines checker in your builds and/or suppress the specific warning. For example, in all my codebases I've shut off the `C26812: The enum type 'x' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).` warning because I don't care for it: It's a recommendation that I can't follow without breaking existing clients of my code, so it's just noise to me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It all makes sense to me. I read through [C++ Core Guidelines checker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers?view=msvc-160) and I decided not to turn off this function to learn better practice since I am still new to C++ who just started learning this language in April this year. I appreciate your help. I hope you have a great Labor Day weekend!

Comment: @yurachika2020 
We are appreciate that you are satisfied with the help. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thank you for your suggestion. I marked it. I didn't know the rule. I appreciate your help!